# Bash Script Not Concatenating Strings

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to concatenate two strings from user input. These are "what to look for" and "what to replace" that text with. It will eventually be a part of a build process. I can't seem to get the variables to correctly concatenate. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=${1}
second=${2}
TO_REPLACE="Hello Kitties=$first"
REPLACEMENT="Hello Kitties=$second"
echo $TO_REPLACE
echo "s/${TO_REPLACE}/${REPLACEMENT}/g"
sed -i "s/${TO_REPLACE}/${REPLACEMENT}/g" "C:\\Test\\Mah.config"
```

I put the echo's in there to troubleshoot along with the `first` and `second` variable. The result I get is this:

```
mrhoden@mrhoden-dt ~
$ bash C:\\Users\\mrhoden\\workspace\\Test\\Concatenation.sh Yes No
Hello Kitties=Yes
/gello Kitties=Noes
```

I don't understand why the first one works fine, but not the second. I even considered the `/` but when I replaced it with a `l` or any other character I'm getting basically the same results. I've tried various ways of grouping the variables and escaping. I even downloaded and used eclipse with the ShellEd plugin in case there was some weird interaction between windows and unix based editors (previously Notepad++).

I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like `$'\r'` from a MSWin line end got into a string.

Comment: `dos2unix file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your script file is in DOS/Windows format (with a carriage return followed by linefeed at the end of each line) rather than unix format (with just linefeed at the end of each line). When the shell executes it, it treats the carriage return (sometimes written `\r`) as part of the command. For example: `first=${1}\r` sets `$first` to the first argument, with a carriage return appended. Then `TO_REPLACE="Hello Kitties=$first"\r` sets `$TO_REPLACE` to that, with *another* carriage return tacked on the end. So when you get to that second echo, what it's actually doing is:

```
echo "s/Hello Kitties=Yes\r\r/Hello Kitties=No\r\r/g"\r
```

When this prints, each carriage return makes the terminal go back to the beginning of the line, so it essentially prints three things, each on top of the last:

```
s/Hello Kitties=Yes
/Hello Kitties=No
/g
```

Leaving you with the combined mess:

```
/gello Kitties=Noes
```

Solution: as @shellter suggested, use `dos2unix` to convert the script to unix format, and then stick to unix-style text editors for scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation, it finally makes sense. If anyone comes along and finds this, you have to re-install cygwin and look under utils to find the dos2unix package.

Comment: Before seeing this answer I was completely befuddled. Excellent explanation! Thanks for saving me another 5 hours!

Comment: Really clear and detailed description of this issue, many hours I wasted to find the correct answer, by the way Notepad++ have a tool to convert to unix format it's in edit->End of line conversions->Unix format